# Kony - Failed to publish the application :- Application or service with name 'BestBuymergeEve' already exists

Tags: temenos-quantum

Tried doing a full publish or update services in kony both options is throwing the below error, Can anyone please help.

Log

```
[01-29-2016 09:06:22]{
  "status_long_message": "Request conflict.",
  "status_short_message": "Conflict",
  "message": "Application or service with name 'BestBuymergeEve' already exists",
  "status": "error",
  "status_code": 409
}
[01-29-2016 09:06:22]Response:HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict [Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8, Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 21:04:19 GMT, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Pragma: no-cache, Server: Apache, X-Kony-RequestId: ee652aef-8819-4005-9153-2329dac1f0b3, Content-Length: 211, Connection: keep-alive]
[01-29-2016 09:06:39]Failed to publish application for 'BestBuymergeEve'. Please see console for error details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your application id then restart the studio and server would resolve the issue.